# What is the wixpdb file for? Is it necessary for deployment?

Tags: wix

After building the installer, I'm provided a cab, msi, and wixpdb file. I've learned you can embed the cab using the `EmbedCab` property of the `MediaTemplate` element, but I've no idea about the wixpdb file. What's its purpose, and is it necessary for a basic installation?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's like a .pdb file for your .exe -- it contains extra symbol information about your .msi. It doesn't get deployed but it can be used later (e.g., to build patches) so you should archive it like you archive other build artifacts.

Comment: So it does not contain symbol information for the actual payload program, but only for the installer, if I understand correctly?

Comment: It contains information about the .msi, which includes the payloads, but not PDB-level symbol information, no.

Comment: Is there any tutorial available for creating patches using wixpdb file? I am unable to find any.

Comment: The Wix documentation for authoring patches using .wixpdb files can be found here: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/patches/#authoring-patches-using-wixpdb-files